# Initializing a class within a static class php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a class responsible for connecting to the database and it returns the connection itself in the construction method

How can I use it inside a static class?

Database.php

```
<?php


class Database {

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $usuario = "root";
    private $senha = "";

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!isset($this->connection))
        {
            $this->connection = new mysqli($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, "netflix_cards", 3308);
            mysqli_set_charset($this->connection, "utf8");
            if(!$this->connection) {
                echo 'Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados';
                exit;
            }

            return $this->connection;
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        return $this->connection->query($this->connection->real_escape_string($query));
    }
?>
```

User.php

```
<?php


class User {

    static function register() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `Database` class?

Comment: Your `query` method is completely wrong. You need to check how to execute queries with mysqli. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement

Comment: @Dharman i am using prepared sql for queries...

Comment: You should read this too: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to avoid purely static class and the singleton pattern (see answer here : [PHP singleton database connection pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832809/php-singleton-database-connection-pattern)

You should instantiate User with `new`, and dependancy-inject an instantiated database connection that you pass around as a parameter where needed.

As someone noted, you should first make your `Database` work properly.